# Testing for nil on a single line in Swift

Tags: swift

I have an optional integer, and I'd like to assign it to a new variable if it's not nil, but assign 0 if it is. I'd also like to do it on a single line. Is there a good reason **not** to do the following?

`let output = input != nil ? input! : 0`

I feel like a more "proper" way would be something like

```
let output = {
    if let _ = input {
        return input!
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}()
```

but it's just so much more verbose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the Swifty way is:

```
let output = input ?? 0
```

The `??` operator, intended for exactly this situation, means: "Unwrap this Optional safely if you can; if you can't, use this alternative value".

Comment: My question was indeed already answered at that other link, but thank you for this. It's such a nice little expression.